# Is it posible to produce onClick event with JMeter?

Tags: onclick, jmeter, stress-testing

I'm trying to create sress test with JMeter and herefor is absolute required to produce mouse `onClick`-event for some elements. But I cannot find any possibility to produce onClick-event with JMeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jMeter doesn't evaluate the HTML or JavaScript that is returned by the webserver, it just captures it.

So, no, you can't do an onClick event with jMeter. What you can do however is extract the url that the onClick event would trigger using the [`Regular Expression Extractor`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), and then feed that url to a new HTTP Sampler.

Comment: please, put a link to the documentation of "Regular Expression Extractor".  Thx.

Comment: Right, that could come in handy :-)   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Answer (score 3):

Jmeter is designed to simulate the server traffic (e.g. HTTP) generated by client (e.g. web browser). It does not simulate the entire browser. So no, you cannot produce or simulate the onClick() event, but you probably can simulate the traffic generated by that event.

To do this, you'll need a tool to capture the requests sent to the server when this onClick() event happens. Then you can model those requests in your JMeter script, just like you've modeled other requests.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter is intended to run load (or general connectivity) tests against a back end service like, for example, a web application running on an application server like Tomcat, Weblogic, WebSphere, etc..

If you would like to 'drive' a browser in a test environment, take a look at tools like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Since you mentioned JMeter, I'm assuming you may want to stick to Java (or the JVM, at least) so you could look at [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) as an alternative to Selenium.

There are many other similar tools, though. Have a look at: http://alternativeto.net/software/selenium

Comment: No Selenium, because I need a `stress test`, not `function test`.

Comment: When you say "`onClick` event for some elements", you are talking about DOM elements in a browser, correct? Are you trying to test the situation where a user would be clicking like crazy in a browser?

Comment: no, not crazy user :) but we have ajax based statistic function, that fired by onClick-Event. And we want to analyze this feature.